# Radio button .isSelected() method doesn't return right response

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I am creating a basic Java GUI trivia game where one selects a radio button, and clicks on a button. The program then checks if the correct radio button was selected. It displays a message based on what radio button is selected. For some reason, even when you select the correct radio button for the first question, it displays "false" even if you selected the correct radio button.

More confusing is that the message "false" is from the second question. The first question displays "False" if you get it wrong. I am quite confused about why this is happening and I would like some help.

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
 {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {

        String recieve = e.getActionCommand ();
        if (recieve.equals("name")) {
            String input = txtName.getText ();
            lblTitle2.setText(input + " want's to be a Millionare!");
        }
        frame1.setVisible (false);
        frame2.setVisible(true);

        int counter = 0;
        if (recieve.equals("q1")) {
            A.setEnabled(true);
            B.setEnabled(true);
            C.setEnabled(true);
            D.setEnabled(true);
            Rbtn1.setEnabled(false);
            lblFill1.setText("What is on the Canadian Quarter?");
            A.setText("Caribou");
            B.setText("Deer");
            C.setText("Schooner");
            D.setText("Seal");
        }
        if (recieve.equals("final") && counter==0) {
            if (A.isSelected()) {
                lblScore.setText("Correct");    
                Rbtn2.setEnabled(true);
                A.setEnabled(false);
                B.setEnabled(false);
                C.setEnabled(false);
                D.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                lblScore.setText("False");  
        }
        }
        counter++;
        if (recieve.equals("q2")) {
            A.setEnabled(true);
            B.setEnabled(true);
            C.setEnabled(true);
            D.setEnabled(true);
            Rbtn2.setEnabled(false);
            lblFill1.setText("The side of a coin with the face is called the?");
            A.setText("Tail");
            B.setText("Head");
            C.setText("Face");
            D.setText("Up");
        }
        if (recieve.equals("final") && counter==1 ) {
                if (B.isSelected()) {
                    lblScore.setText("correct");    
                    Rbtn3.setEnabled(true);

                }
                else {
                    lblScore.setText("false");
                }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You could remove every use of the `counter` variable and the code will function exactly the same.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. ..

Comment: .. `frame1.setVisible (false); frame2.setVisible(true);` 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 4) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Put the counter declaration outside:

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
 {
int counter = 0;
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
```

Put the

```
counter ++;
```

after a succesfull answer, like

```
if (A.isSelected()) {
 counter ++;
```